# .hide() works but .slideUp() doesn't

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jQuery's `.slideUp()` method on all elements of class `row` when any element of class `button` is clicked, but nothing seems to happen when I click on a button. However, when I swap out `.slideUp()` for `.hide()`, the `row` elements do indeed hide. What might be causing this?

I am using Bootstrap, in case that matters.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

    <head>

        <!-- required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styles.css">

        <!-- http://jquery.com/ -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- app's own JavaScript -->
        <script src="/static/scripts.js"></script>

        <title>Happiness Goals: {% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>

    </head>

    <body>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Happiness Goals</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                {% if session.user_id %}
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/set">Set</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/track">Track</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/change_password">Change Password</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/logout">Log Out</a></li>
                    </ul>
                {% else %}
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/register">Register</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/login">Login</a></li>
                    </ul>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </nav>

        <main class="container p-5">

            {% with errors = errors %}
                {% if errors %}
                    <div>
                        <ul class="errors">
                        {% for error in errors %}
                            <li>{{ error }}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            {% endwith %}

            {% block main %}{% endblock %}

        </main>

        <!-- Bootstrap Javascript links -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

My main block on this page:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Home
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <div class="row" id="cards1">
      <div class="card-deck">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="{{url_for('static', filename='asanas.jpg')}}" alt="exercise_image">
          <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
            <h5 class="card-title">Physical Health</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Take care of your body</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Set a Goal</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="{{url_for('static', filename='thanks2.png')}}" alt="exercise_image">
          <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
            <h5 class="card-title">Gratitude</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Count your blessings</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Set a Goal</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="{{url_for('static', filename='friends2.jpg')}}" alt="exercise_image" >
          <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
            <h5 class="card-title">Relationships</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Feel the love</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Set a Goal</a>
          </div>
        </div>


      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row pt-4" id="cards2">
      <div class="card-deck">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{{url_for('static', filename='volunteer.png')}}" alt="exercise_image" >
          <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
            <h5 class="card-title">Giving Back</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Help others and feel useful</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary mt-auto">Set a Goal</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{{url_for('static', filename='spirituality.png')}}" alt="exercise_image" >
          <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
            <h5 class="card-title">Spirituality</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Connect to something larger than yourself</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Set a Goal</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{{url_for('static', filename='old.png')}}" alt="exercise_image" >
          <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
            <h5 class="card-title">Other</h5>
            <p class="card-text">You know you best! What do you think will make you happy?</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Set a Goal</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


{% endblock %}
```

JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( ".btn" ).click(function () {
        $( ".row" ).slideUp();
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
main .form-group
{
    /* override Bootstrap's default 100% width for form input elements */
    width: 30%;

    /* center form inputs */
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

main
{
    /* center contents */
    text-align:center;
}

.errors
{
    /* red color for errors */
    color: #FF0000;

    /* center error list items */
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
}

.card
{
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Kind of a negative proof here, it seems to work just fine. See functioning snippet below. Are you seeing any .js errors in the console?

Comment: Yes, sorry I am just starting out and didn't think to check. I am getting a "TypeError: $(...).slideUp is not a function" error.

Comment: @JasonB I added my links to the post

Comment: So it looks like you are trying to load jQuery twice, once from jQuery.com and once from Google. Adding both of those lines to the code snippet here didn't break it in Chrome for me. That error makes it seem like jQuery isn't loaded or it is haveing a conflict. Try replacing the $ with jQuery as in jQuery( document ).ready(... and see if you get a similar error.

Comment: I actually originally only loaded jQuery directly from jQuery, but saw in your code below that you loaded from jQuery and Google so added Google.

I replaced $ with jQuery but no dice.

Comment: did you then get the error TypeError: jQuery(...).slideUp is not a function?

Comment: Yes, I got the same error. The error in full is: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slideUp is not a function
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (scripts.js:3)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)`

Comment: Looks like you are actually using a slim version of jQuery which doesn't have the slideUp function. Double check the link you are using. Now that I see the error, I was able to load a slim version of jQuery and got the same error. jQuery links - https://code.jquery.com/

Comment: Ahh. Ok. Once I added the link to the full version of jQuery and deleted the link to the slim version from both my header and from the end of my body (where I had added as per the Bootstrap Getting Started guide), it worked! Thank you for being patient with a silly problem.

Comment: Glad to help - that's how we all learn. Becoming skilled at interpreting the error messages is as important as learning to write the code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you narrow it down, and I will delete this answer if necessary, but this code seems to work just fine with Bootstrap4.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( ".btn" ).click(function () {
        $( ".row" ).slideUp();
    });
});
```

```css
main .form-group
{
    /* override Bootstrap's default 100% width for form input elements */
    width: 30%;

    /* center form inputs */
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

main
{
    /* center contents */
    text-align:center;
}

.errors
{
    /* red color for errors */
    color: #FF0000;

    /* center error list items */
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
}

.card
{
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
<div class="row" id="cards1">
  <div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="{{url_for('static', filename='asanas.jpg')}}" alt="exercise_image">
      <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
        <h5 class="card-title">Physical Health</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Take care of your body</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Set a Goal</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="{{url_for('static', filename='asanas.jpg')}}" alt="exercise_image">
      <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
        <h5 class="card-title">Physical Health</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Take care of your body</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Set a Goal</a>
      </div>
    </div>

     <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="{{url_for('static', filename='asanas.jpg')}}" alt="exercise_image">
      <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
        <h5 class="card-title">Physical Health</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Take care of your body</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Set a Goal</a>
      </div>

  </div>

</div>
```